# I need to remove the empty p tags

Tags: twig, twig-filter

```
{{ link_content_override|replace({'<p>':'<span>'})|raw }}
```

This is my actual twig file in which I have used replace filter to change all the p tags into span tags. But still I am getting empty p tags from drupal. I need to remove those empty p tags. The parent tag for the actual twig file is a heading tag. p tag inside heading tag is not advisable so trying to remove the p tag alone.

Expected HTML:

```
  <h3>
    <a class="heading__link" href="/rice-products/all">
      <span>Hero
      <span><span style="font-size: 16px; line-height: 16px;">Banner</span>
      <span>Text
      </span></span></span>
    </a>
   </h3>
```

But Actual HTML:

```
   <h3>
    <a class="heading__link" href="/rice-products/all">
       <span>Hero<p></p>
       <span><span style="font-size: 16px; line-height: 16px;">Banner</span><p></p>
       <span>Text<p></p>
       </span></span></span>
     </a>
    </h3>
```

On using striptags and providing allowable tags we are able to allow only the specified tags inside striptags but in my case I just need to get rid of p tags alone. I am new to twig files. Can someone help me in achieving the solution

Comment: Do note `replace` is chaining `str_replace` in the background. Meaning putting just `|replace({'<p>':'<span>',})` *won't replace* `</p>` with `</span>`.

Comment: @DarkBee how to proceed further then? I am stuck with this for the past 3 days.

Comment: If you don't care about extra spaces, you can use `{{ html|replace({'<p></p>': '', '<p>': '<span>', '</p>': '</span>',})|raw }}`, if you do, you'll need to add a twig filter/function and parse html with a domparser - [demo](https://twigfiddle.com/embt2s)